# Scheduled Posts preview throwing 404 on some subsites within a wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, multisite

I am facing a strange issue within my wordpress multisite setup with 5 sub sites. i am using revisions plugin to schedule posts.so when a post is scheduled and i hit for a preview for the post its throwing 404 page not found. strangely its happening on two of the sub sites , while the others are working fine.

- My permalink structure is set to post
- i am using mu domain mapping plugin
- I have reset the permalink to default but its not solved anything
- Disabled and renabled the schedule plugin but no luck

Please help me resolve the issue . thanks

Comment: Are there any mistakes in logs when you do it?

Comment: i have not checked the logs yet. i will check it and post it . there is no error on the console.

Comment: This is what is showing on the debug log for wp. 

[09-Jul-2021 11:57:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/bearhill/wp-content/plugins/so-widgets-bundle/compat/block-editor/widget-block.php on line 48